# Map Postgis Point to Point in C# using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, postgresql, fluent-nhibernate, postgis, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I am working on Mapping Spatial geometry(Point) On Postgresql to C# Code I need something like example in this question [like example in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059292/geospatial-point-mapping-in-fluent-nhibernate) but using Postgresql Instead of SQL Server

I did the following

```
public class Student
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Point Location { get; set; }
}

public class StudentMap : ClassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.Name);
        Map(x => x.Location).CustomType<PostGisPointUserTypeConvention>();
        Table("Student");
    }
}
```

And tried to use UserTypeConvention as below

```
public class PostGisPointUserTypeConvention : UserTypeConvention<PostGisGeometryType>
{
    public override void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(c => c.Type == typeof(Point));
    }

    public override void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        // Have to set CustomType to be able to read/write rows using NHibernate
        instance.CustomType<PostGisGeometryType>();
        // Have to set CustomSqlType to generate correct SQL schema
        instance.CustomSqlType("geometry(Point)");
    }
}
```

The configuration of the Fluent NHibernate is

```
public class Database
{
    private static ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;

    private static ISessionFactory SessionFactory
    {
        get
        {
            if (_sessionFactory == null)
                _sessionFactory = InitializeSessionFactory(); return _sessionFactory;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This Function working fine with Map class in the projects
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static ISessionFactory InitializeSessionFactory()
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["PostgreConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        IPersistenceConfigurer config = PostgreSQLConfiguration.PostgreSQL82.ConnectionString(connectionString);

        FluentConfiguration configuration = Fluently
            .Configure()
            .Database(config)
            .Mappings(m =>
                m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
        configuration.ExposeConfiguration(x => x.SetProperty("hbm2ddl.keywords", "auto-quote"));
        return configuration.BuildSessionFactory();
    }
    public static ISession OpenSession()
    {
        return SessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }
}
```

When Try to run below

```
public void GET()
    {
        using (var session = Database.OpenSession())
        {
            // populate the database
            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
            {
                Point loc = new Point(38.690993, 38.690993);
                var student = new Student
                {
                    Name = "Nehal",
                    Age = 20,
                    Location = loc
                };

                session.Save(student);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }

    }
```

It give me exception when run Database.OpenSession() as below:

> FluentNHibernate.Cfg.FluentConfigurationException: "An invalid or
>   incomplete configuration was used while creating a SessionFactory.
>   Check PotentialReasons collection, and InnerException for more
>   detail."
>
> Inner Exception: "An invalid or incomplete configuration was used
>   while creating a SessionFactory. Check PotentialReasons collection,
>   and InnerException for more detail."
>
> Loader Exception: System.IO.FileLoadException Could not load file or
>   assembly 'GeoAPI, Version=1.7.4.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=a1a0da7def465678' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)":"GeoAPI,
>   Version=1.7.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a1a0da7def465678

But I didn't use GeoAPI in any c# classes I created

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using the `Point` geometry type from the `NetTopologySuite` namespace? If so, the `GeoAPI` library is one of its dependencies.

How are you currently referencing `NetTopologySuite` in your project? If you are not already using NuGet, I would highly recommend it since it will automatically take care of installing all the necessary dependencies for you (see [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetTopologySuite/) for the NTS NuGet page).